# How to display the remaining memory in alerts (node_filesystem_avail_bytes metric)

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Good afternoon I have a problem. I want to display the remaining memory in alerts, which takes the value of the node_filesystem_avail_bytes metric and divides it by / 1024 / 1024 (to convert to Mb).

Now my rule looks like this:

```yaml
   - alert: HostOutOfDiskSpace_test
     expr: (node_filesystem_avail_bytes * 100) / node_filesystem_size_bytes > 0 and ON (instance, device, mountpoint) node_filesystem_readonly == 0 and {instance=~"10.22.22.18.*"}
     for: 1s
     labels:
       severity: high
     annotations:
       summary: "Host {{ $labels.instance }} out of memory \n - Device: {{ $labels.device }} \n - Mountpoint - {{ $labels.mountpoint }}"
       description: "Node memory is filling up. Value = {{ $value | printf `%.2f` }} ({{ printf \"node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint='%s'}\" .Labels.mountpoint | query | first | value|humanize1024}})"
```

But the value is displayed incorrectly. Prometheus shows the correct values of the node_filesystem_avail_bytes metrics, but in the notification it is not recalculated correctly. Here are examples of notifications from telegrams:

```
 [PROBLEM] HostOutOfDiskSpace_test_1
Severity: high
Summary: Host 10.22.22.181:9100 out of memory
    - Device: /dev/sda1
    - Mountpoint - /boot
Description: Node memory is filling up. Value = 72.62 (736.4Mi)
Starts at: 2023-08-15 16:19:52.25 +0300 MSK
____________________

 [PROBLEM] HostOutOfDiskSpace_test_1
Severity: high
Summary: Host 10.22.22.181:9100 out of memory
    - Device: tmpfs
    - Mountpoint - /run
Description: Node memory is filling up. Value = 98.14 (298.2Mi)
Starts at: 2023-08-15 16:19:52.25 +0300 MSK
____________________

 [PROBLEM] HostOutOfDiskSpace_test_1
Severity: high
Summary: Host 10.22.22.181:9100 out of memory
    - Device: tmpfs
    - Mountpoint - /run/user/1000
Description: Node memory is filling up. Value = 100.00 (298.8Mi)
Starts at: 2023-08-15 16:19:52.25 +0300 MSK
____________________

 [PROBLEM] HostOutOfDiskSpace_test_1
Severity: high
Summary: Host 10.22.22.181:9100 out of memory
    - Device: /dev/mapper/rhel-root
    - Mountpoint - /
Description: Node memory is filling up. Value = 87.08 (31.48Gi)
Starts at: 2023-08-15 16:19:52.25 +0300 MSK
```

---

At the same time, Prometheus shows the following values:

```
{device="/dev/mapper/rhel-root", fstype="xfs", instance="10.22.22.181:9100", mountpoint="/"} 15146.296875
{device="/dev/sda1", fstype="xfs", instance="10.22.22.181:9100", mountpoint="/boot"} 736.39453125
{device="tmpfs", fstype="tmpfs", instance="10.22.22.181:9100", mountpoint="/run"} 872.640625
{device="tmpfs", fstype="tmpfs", instance="10.22.22.181:9100", mountpoint="/run/user/1000"} 177.83984375
```

Here is the output from the OS:

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs 871M 0 871M 0% /dev
tmpfs 890M 0 890M 0% /dev/shm
tmpfs 890M 17M 873M 2% /run
tmpfs 890M 0 890M 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-root 17G 2.2G 15G 13% /
/dev/sda1 1014M 278M 737M 28% /boot
tmpfs 178M 0 178M 0% /run/user/1000
```

Reading the official documentation from the prometheus.io website, I realized that the problem was in the translation of the data. I need one rule to work for different devices and mount points. The construct `{{ printf \"node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint='%s'}\" .Labels.mountpoint | query | first | value | humanize1024 }}` works the way I want it to, but the mountpoint string that contains the given value doesn't translate correctly to `humanize1024`. `humanize` very far from real values, so I don't consider it.

Maybe someone has come across this. How can I display node_filesystem_avail_bytes associated with a specific device and mount point, bypassing the humanize1024 function, but simply dividing by / 1024 / 1024 or some other conversion to MB or GB?

Comment: Shouldn't your query (the inner one) use not only mountpoint selector, but also instance? Something like `printf "node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint='%s', instance='%s'}"  .Labels.mountpoint  .Labels.instance | query ...`

Comment: Thank you! I added a binding to instance, and not just to mountpoint, and everything worked as it should.
Working result: {{ printf \"node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint='%s', instance='%s'}\" .Labels.mountpoint .Labels.instance | query | first | value | humanize1024 }}

Comment: I believe this question should be closed, as it looks like the case of misunderstanding (or even typo), and probably wouldn't be helpful to anyone. But on the other hand, consider asking a separate question about how to include into summary metric queried based on multiple labels of current expression, this might help "future generations".

Answer (score 0):

I added a binding to instance, and not just to mountpoint, and everything worked as it should.

Working result: {{ printf "node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint='%s', instance='%s'}" .Labels.mountpoint .Labels.instance | query | first | value | humanize1024 }}